# Iterate through a list of ids, find other attributes on repo and set them into another list

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-boot, dto

I have a function that accepts *List id* as a @RequestBody parameter.

I need to find each id's other variables (message,date,noofp), set them in a list of DTO objects.

```
public class DataDTO {
        private long id;

    private String message;

    private Date date;

    private String noofp;

    private String meaningofp;
}
```

```
List<DataDTO> rpaDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        
//this part is where I am confused
         id.forEach(x-> {
            repository.findById(x).map( rpa -> {
            ??????????
            })  
        });
        
return repository.saveAll(rpaDataList);
```

How can i do it ?

The logic in my head is that I need to iterarte through list of ids, find each id in repository and get other informations. Set them in a DTO object, put these objects into a list and use saveAll method.

Can't seem to put it on code.

Comment: Don't. Issue a single query to get everything and let JPA do the mapping to a DTO. Also why would you need to save a dto?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I know it's the right one. But for some reasons I need to do it this way. So I need an answer that can be done with the logic I mentioned above. It would be really helpful to talk about that

Comment: There is no reason to not do it the way described the result is the same with better performance and memory usage. Yours will be slow because you issue x queries, retrieve too much data and do everything in memory. Use the tools you have not around them.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I'm sure it's true. The goal here is not performance, but learning these processes. It's not about saving dto or performance that matters to me. Understanding the operations in lists is my priority. As you can imagine, I'm a beginner and I asked this question in this way to learn it and to explain it more clearly. Otherwise, I could only ask for the list part. Like I said, I need to learn how to convert the above logic to code. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: if you are a beginner you should learn the proper way not the wrong way. Yours is the wrong way. But if you really want you should use a stream, twice a map (first the retrieval of the entity, then a map to convert entity to a dto). Then do a toList. But as stated you should really learn the proper way and not the wrong way, if you learn the wrong way you are going to apply it in real projects as well with all consequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using java streams like this

```
List<DataDTO> rpaDataList = id.stream().map(x -> repository.findById(x)).filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get).toList();
repository.saveAll(rpaDataList);
```